# How to fix boolean-methods "unexpected token: boolean/void" in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I try to create a Class in Processing,
it includes 3 bool´s, and I want to make a getter, setter, resp. a method which changes the boolean to the other value.
That´s it.
My Code is following:

```
public class Color_high_low {
  private boolean r_higher = true;
  private boolean g_higher = true;
  private boolean b_higher = true;

  Color_high_low() {
    r_higher = true;
    g_higher = true;
    b_higher = true;
  }

  //Getter

  {
    boolean get_r_h() {
      return r_higher;
    }

    boolean get_g_h() {
      return this.r_higher;
    }

    boolean get_b_h() {
      return this.r_higher;
    }
  }

  //Changer
  {
    void change_r_h() {
      if (r_higher == true) {
        r_higher = false;
      } else {
        r_higher = true;
      }
      return;
    }

    void change_g_h() {
      if (g_higher == true) {
        g_higher = false;
      } else {
        g_higher = true;
      }
      return;
    }

    void change_b_h() {
      if (b_higher == true) {
        b_higher = false;
      } else {
        b_higher = true;
      }
      return;
    }
  }
  //Setter
  {
    void set_r_h(boolean be_or_not_to_be) {
      r_higher = be_or_not_to_be;
      return;
    }

    void set_g_h(boolean be_or_not_to_be) {
      g_higher = be_or_not_to_be;
      return;
    }

    void set_b_h(boolean be_or_not_to_be) {
      b_higher = be_or_not_to_be;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

At the moment I get compile errors by the Return-Types of my methods, but I don´t know why. Do you have ideas?
Answers would be a pleasure!

Compile errors at the moment:

```
unexpected token: boolean

unexpected token: void
```

Comment: You have an extra `{` above a lot of your methods. As well as some extra `}`

Comment: You have put an extra `{` and `}` around each group of three methods (getters, changers and setters). Try removing them both.

Comment: you are right....

Answer (score 1):

Don´t put methods in extra backets {} for grouping!

Comment: If the blocks are labelled that's fine: *getter : {...}*.

Comment: Rather than commenting ( "//" ) label the block with a name followed by a colon.